# Primefaces Datatable with global data filtering feature issues

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces datatable  with filtering options . I have retreive the list of values in datatable with global data filtering features. I have select the particular rows through selectBoolean checkbox from the datatable. Without filtering the rows and select the checkbox means,the corressponding selected values are done.But when i have search the particular values through filtering options and select the rows means defaultly i got the first rows values only. For example i have search the last values from table and select that rows,but i got the first rows values.

Jsf Page :

```
<p:dataTable emptyMessage="No values found with given criteria" id="ng1" var="ngo"
             widgetVar="ngoS" paginator="true" rows="15" paginatorPosition="bottom"
             value="#{approveControl.appNgo}"  paginatorAlwaysVisible="false">
    <f:facet name="header">  
        <p:outputPanel>  
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
             <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="ngoS.filter()" style="width:150px" />  
        </p:outputPanel>  
    </f:facet>

    <p:column filterBy="#{ngo.name}"   headerText="NgoName">  
        #{ngo.name}
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Email" filterBy="#{ngo.email_id}">  
        #{ngo.email_id}
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Select">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="list" value="#{approveControl.checked[ngo.ngo_id]}" />
    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">  
        <h:inputHidden rendered="#{!approveControl.appNgo.isEmpty()}">
            <p:commandButton  value="Reject" onclick="onSubmit(#{approveControl.appNgo.size()});" />
        </h:inputHidden>
     </f:facet>  
</p:dataTable>
```

I am using Primefaces 3.0 and jsf 2.0. how can i solve it.

Comment: you should use `rendered` within `<p:commandButton>`